# File::Find to search through directory and subdirectories, use pattern match to store successful matches to array

Tags: perl

1. The pattern I want to match is `*_name.txt`
2. The directory I want to search is $dir ($dir has many subdirectories, which is why I need [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) rather than [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)
3. I am not going to use [`Find::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) ( I know it has easy code for this, but when I ran, it had non-existing file errors.  I do not want to add additional files to my perl library)

The syntax I have so far is

```
use File::Find;
find(\&store_foundfiles,$dir);
sub store_foundfiles {
  my @string = *_name.txt;
  #I DONT KNOW FROM HERE ON"
  #I WANT TO IMPLEMENT THE FOLLOWING...
  #FOREACH MATCH ON @string, STORE THE MATCH TO ARRAY '@found'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding this because *most* people should probably use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3AFind%3A%3ARule) for this, even if you have a reason not to:

```
use File::Find::Rule;
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->name("*_name.txt")->in($dir);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
my @found;
find(
    sub {
        push @found, $File::Find::name if /_name[.]txt\z/;
        # or push @found, $File::Find::name if substr($_, -9) eq '_name.txt';
    }, 
    $dir,
);
for my $file (@found) { ... }
```

The array is declared outside of the subroutine so it sticks around outside of the subroutine's scope. If you have a very large number of files, you may want to process each one as it's encountered rather than storing them all in an array and looping through that (NB: some operations cannot be done lazily, like sorting).

`$File::Find::name` is pushed rather than `$_` because the absolute path is likely more useful. Push `$_` instead if you just want the base filename.